# "Six month post grant review" ?? I assume this has been added to the boiler plate? It is not correct

Tags: discussion

From the USPTO FAQs on this program: it is in effect only for applications with a filing date after March 15,20013

It is nine months not six months. It is not a "send in documents" program. It is a complex quasi judicial adversarial  proceeding that will be expensive. $12k fee just to start. It's goal is to be a bargin in comparision to actual patent lawsuits.

There is another program that is a more of a send in documents program. Ex parte reexamination request allows a third party to attempt to get the ball rolling (for $6k) and if the USPTO thinks the documents and reasoning present a significant new question of patentability they take it from there. You get your $6k back if they decide it is not going to be re-opened.